# How to explain following terms (Cursor, Context, DatabaseHelper)

Tags: android

If some one asks you: What are those terms standing for?

How do you explain it to people with no develeopment experience?

Comment: why would you need to explain such details to a non-developer...?

Comment: because my teacher needs those details in my presentation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per my knowledge what i understand this terms, i pasting here..

> **Cursor:** Retrieving data from SQLite databases in Android is done using Cursors. The Android SQLite query method returns a Cursor object
>   containing the results of the query.Cursors store query result records
>   in rows and grant many methods to access and iterate through the
>   records.To use Cursors android.database.Cursor must be imported.
>
> **Context:** Context is an interface to global information about an application environment. It's an abstract class whose implementation
>   is provided by the Android system.
>
> Context allows access to application-specific resources and classes,
>   as well as calls for application-level operations such as launching
>   activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.
>
> All the widgets receive a Context parameter in their constructor. In a
>   regular Android application, you usually have two kinds of Context,
>   Activity and Application. It's usually an Activity Context that the
>   developer passes to classes and methods that need a Context.
>
> **DatabaseHelper Class:** A good practice for dealing with databases is to create a helper class to encapsulate all the complexities of
>   accessing the database so that it's transparent to the calling code.
>   So, create a helper class called DBAdapter that creates, opens,
>   closes, and uses a SQLite database.